# Don't Show Read More Button if Content is Not Overflowing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my school project i'm checking if the content inside `div` is overflown, if it's overflown then do nothing but if it's not overflown then don't show the `Read more` link/button.

Here's my code,

```
<div class="hideContent">{{ content }}</div>
<div><a class="showLink" href="#">Read more</a></div>
```

EDIT:

Both of these divs are  inside a for loop so Content & `Read more` is showing multiple times on page.

Here's the css,

```
.hideContent{
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Here's how I'm checking if the Content is Overflown.

```
var getElements = document.querySelectorAll('.hideContent');

Array.from(getElements).forEach(function(element) {
  if ((element.offsetHeight < element.scrollHeight) || (element.offsetWidth < element.scrollWidth)) {
    // Do Nothing
  } else {

    If content is not overflown then hide the `Read more` Link!

  }
});
```

How can we hide the `Read more` link in case if the content is not overflowing? Thank You . . .

Comment: do you have multiple content div as well as there corresponding read-more links?

Comment: @AlivetoDie Sir, it's inside a for loop. So, Content is showing multiple times along-with `Read more` link

Comment: "How can we hide the link" - `$(element).next().find(".showLink").hide();`  - what am I missing?

Comment: @freedomn-m Thank You Sir. It's working perfectly fine :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you script code condition is working fine, so just add in `else` part:-

```
$(element).next().find(".showLink").hide();
```

***Working snippet:-***

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var getElements = document.querySelectorAll('.hideContent');
  Array.from(getElements).forEach(function(element) {
    if ((element.offsetHeight < element.scrollHeight) || (element.offsetWidth < element.scrollWidth)) {
      // Do Nothing
    } else {
      $(element).next().find(".showLink").hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.hideContent{
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hideContent">
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

</div>

<div><a class="showLink" href="#">Read more</a></div>

<div class="hideContent">
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>

<div><a class="showLink" href="#">Read more</a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So far, your check is good.
When you do the inverse if-condition, you can discard the else-block.

In vanilla JavaScript/DOM the hiding of an element can be done by setting the [element].hidden attribute to true.

The next (DOM-)Element can be get by [element].nextElementSibling

```js
var getElements = document.querySelectorAll('.hideContent');
Array.from(getElements).forEach(function(el) {
    if (el.offsetHeight >= el.scrollHeight && el.offsetWidth >= el.scrollWidth)
        el.nextElementSibling.hidden = true;
});
```

```css
.hideContent{
    max-height: 200px;
    max-width: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="hideContent" style="background:#bea;">this element don't have a "Read more"-Block</div>
<div><a class="showLink" href="#">Read more</a></div><br>
<div class="hideContent">
    <div style="background:#bada55; width:220px;">This element is to wide, so it shows the "Read more"-Block</div>
</div>
<div><a class="showLink" href="#">Read more</a></div>
<div class="hideContent">
    <div style="background:#bada55; height: 220px;">This element is to high</div>
</div>
<div><a class="showLink" href="#">Read more</a></div>
```

Comment: Thank You Sir :) `$(element).next().find(".showLink").hide();` worked perfectly fine :)